# Procedures to safely perform SQL Server Always On database cluster failover during Updates & Patching?

Tags: availability-groups, sql-server-2017, clustering, failover, failover-cluster-instance

I need some steps and guidance, to perform the Microsoft Cluster Failover (MSCS 2016) for my **SQL Server 2017 Enterprise Edition – Always-On** 2x nodes.

This is to perform the Windows Server updates that will be rebooting one SQL Server node over the other.

I got confused between these two procedures:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/use-the-fail-over-availability-group-wizard-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver15

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/perform-a-planned-manual-failover-of-an-availability-group-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about those docs is confusing to you? They are very detailed about the steps needed to perform an AG Failover. Adding details to your question on what is confusing, or at what point you need help understanding will be necessary to answering your questions. Without that, any answer will likely be just a summary of those linked docs, which isn't likely to address your confusion.

Comment: Why I can't just  perform the Failover from the Failover cluster console or from the Windows Admin Console https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/use/manage-failover-clusters

I'm trying to do this via the Windows Admin Console of other GUI methods, outside of the SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer as I remember it is NOT recommended doing so, you should do failover only using SSMS AG dashboard